# snap/kodi:apparmor blocks dvd

Tags: snap, apparmor, kodi

Would be nice to use dvd in the kodi-snap in the cosmic's software-center, but it somehow seems to be blocked by apparmor:

```
audit[10035]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kodi.kodi" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/media/jarosch/SOME_NICE_FILM/" pid=10035 comm="kodi.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
audit: type=1400 audit(1551807964.170:48): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.kodi.kodi" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/media/jarosch/SOME_NICE_FILM/" pid=10035 comm="kodi.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the kodi-snap, but have you made sure all its interfaces are connected?

Comment: You will find the apparmor policy definitions in `/etc/apparmor.d/` - If you want to fight with it, you can try to tune the policies defined in a file named like 'snap.kodi.kodi' - My prefered option : remove the snap package of kodi and install it from repository with `apt`.

Comment: You could ask here - https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/snap

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the `removable-media` interface.

```
$ snap connect kodi:removable-media
```

The `optical-drive` interface should be auto-connect and I believe it's declared for kodi. The removable-media interface on the other hand is not auto-connect. It's possible your system is not recognizing `/media/jarosch/` as an optical-drive.

Comment: Unfortunately, the snap command you posted didn't change anything. I'm - by the way - not familiar with snap at all and don't know how to check if the interfaces are connected. While it's getting complicated, I'd rather use VLC for DVDs and hope the best that disco will fix it all… Just less than two months to go…

Comment: `snap interfaces kodi` should display all the interfaces the snap needs and if any are unplugged.